# Push Notifications are not coming during foreground in Angular IONIC Hybrid Application in IOS device

Tags: swift, angular, cordova

I have integrated firebase for push notifications in Anuglar IONIC Application. If the app is in foreground I am receiving notifications properly in android. Also when I run the ios application from XCode notifications are working fine. However in release ipa notifications are not received in foreground but working well in app background state. I have enabled push notifications and background fetch as well. Any solution for this? Has anybody faced such issue?

I have added all below possibilities, but none of them .

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // Called when the app was launched with an activity, including Universal Links.
    // Feel free to add additional processing here, but if you want the App API to support
    // tracking app url opens, make sure to keep this call
    return ApplicationDelegateProxy.shared.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
}


// These delegate methods MUST live in App Delegate and nowhere else!

// If the app is in the background
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let id = response.notification.request.identifier
    print("Received notification with ID = \(id)")
    
    completionHandler()
}

// If the app is in the foreground
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let id = notification.request.identifier
    print("Received notification with ID = \(id)")
    
    completionHandler([.sound, .alert])
}

//    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
//                                   willPresent notification: UNNotification,
//                                   withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
//           //TODO: Handle foreground notification
//           print("Its completion Handler")
//           //          print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
//           if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
//               completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound,.banner])
//           } else {
//               // Fallback on earlier versions
//               completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
//           };
//       }
```

}